# Number of different elements up to this point

Tags: r, vector, unique

I've got a relatively simple problem (I think) and I want to solve it in a *fast* and efficient way.

I want to count the number of *different elements* in a vector up to each point in this vector.

For example, in a vector like this

`vec <- c("a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "c", "d", "a")`

I want to get the following vector of equal size as a result:
`[1 2 3 3 3 3 4 4]`

I could solve this of course with a `for` loop in combination with `cumsum()`:

```
vec <- c("a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "c", "d", "a")
res <- T
for (i in 2:length(vec)) {
  res[i] <- !(vec[i] %in% vec[1:(i-1)])
}
cumsum(res)
[1] 1 2 3 3 3 3 4 4
```

However, I am dealing with vectors that have several million elements and a for-loop approach takes forever for such a relatively simple problem.

I have the intuition that this should be solvable much faster and more clever. Do you have any ideas? Thank you!

(In case you're interested: I need this for a vocabulary growth curve analysis where we want to know at each point in the text how many different words, i.e. types, have been observed so far.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `cumsum` on the non (`!`) `duplicated` values:

```r
cumsum(!duplicated(vec))
#[1] 1 2 3 3 3 3 4 4
```

---

And another approach with `match`:

```r
uni <- vector(length = length(vec))
uni[match(unique(vec), vec)] <- TRUE
cumsum(uni)
```

Comment: :o "duplicated() determines which elements of a vector or data frame are duplicates of elements with smaller subscripts" – I was not a aware of the fact that duplicated() operates this way!! Thank you so much!

Comment: yes, `duplicated` is very cool!

Answer (score 3):

I believe the `duplicated` approach by [@Maël](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77613836/12158757) is the most efficient, cheers!

An alternative could be using `cummax` + `factor` (or `match`), e.g., but it would be ***slower*** than `cumsum` + `duplicated`

```
> cummax(as.integer(factor(vec, levels = unique(vec))))
[1] 1 2 3 3 3 3 4 4

> cummax(match(vec, unique(vec)))
[1] 1 2 3 3 3 3 4 4
```

and benchmarking

```
set.seed(0)
vec <- sample(c(letters, LETTERS), 1e6, TRUE)
microbenchmark(
    cumsum = cumsum(!duplicated(vec)),
    cummax1 = cummax(as.integer(factor(vec, levels = unique(vec)))),
    cummax2 = cummax(match(vec, unique(vec))),
    check = "equivalent",
    unit = "relative"
)
```

shows

```
Unit: relative
    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
  cumsum 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.0000000   100
 cummax1 1.945930 1.879805 1.577003 1.684878 1.544305 0.7344597   100
 cummax2 1.974178 1.870829 1.611623 1.713824 1.510238 1.3714560   100
```

---

Here is another way, not efficient, but you can ***keep track of the cumulative updating***

```
> Reduce(union, vec, accumulate = TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "a" "b"

[[3]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

[[4]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

[[5]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

[[6]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

[[7]]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

[[8]]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

and the length growth

```
> lengths(Reduce(union, vec, accumulate = TRUE))
[1] 1 2 3 3 3 3 4 4
```

Comment: Oh, this is also a very nice solution. It's also MUCH faster than the for loop but considerable slower than the duplicated solution.

Comment: @swolf yes, it is used for tracing the evolution of `res`